# MySQL-SSL Configuration on Windows Machine ( openSSl, Mysql 5.1, IIS 5.0)

Tags: mysql, iis, openssl

how to setup openssl at the mysql? "have_ssl" disabled; how to enable it?

"
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_ssl';

If the value is YES, the server supports SSL connections. If the value is DISABLED, the server supports SSL connections but was not started with the appropriate --ssl-xxx  options"

there is not very clear. how to enable it to ask the server support SSL connections ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to creat key first and put them on the my.ini file.

there are good tutorials, which I read :
mysql-traffic-encryption-with-openssl.html 
connecting-to-mysql-using-ssl-encryption-in-ruby-on-rails/
support.eapps.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=122&nav=0,1

Solved it already